# When should I declare function return types?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am confused about where and how often I should declare function return types in common lisp.  If I understand correctly, no implementation is required to use the information provided by the declarations, and when the information is used, the effects are not well defined and probably not consistent across different implementations, so **this is more of a question of best practices than formal definitions**.  Please keep that in mind if you try to answer these.  Basically, this is what I want to know: Assuming that I'm aiming for maximal efficiency (`(optimize (debug 0) (safety 0) speed)`), when do function return type declarations provide, **in principle**, useful information that the compiler can use for optimization?  That's a broad question, and I'll take broad answers; but to give a better idea of what I'm after, let me break it down into a couple of specific questions.  Given the following definitions:

```
(defun foo (a)
  (the <type> <form>))

(defun bar (a)
  (foo a))

(defun baz (a)
  (bar a))
```

a. Can the compiler optimize calls to `BAZ`, or should the return forms in `BAR` and `BAZ` be wrapped in a (seemingly redundant) `THE` form like it is in `FOO`? In other words, will the compiler know to treat `(bar <form>)` as `(the <type> (bar <form>))` without me saying so explicitly?

b. Do the relative order of the three definitions affect the answer to (a)?

c. If the above definitions occurred in three separate source files that got compiled into three separate fasl files, how would that change the answer to (a)?

d. Given the following:

```
(let ((var1 (foo <form1>))
      (var2 (bar <form2>))
      (var3 (baz <form3>)))
  <form>*)
```

Can/will the compiler correctly infer the types of (the objects bound to) `VAR1`, `VAR2`, and `VAR3` within the body of the `LET` without explicit type declarations, or should I add another `DECLARE` form right after the bindings?

e. Supposing that the `LET` from question (d) occurs in a file other than the file(s) in which the three functions are defined, what effect will the following declarations:

```
(declaim (ftype (function (t) <type>) foo bar baz))
```

at the top of the file have on the answer to (d)?

Comment: Common Lisp is a language specification. How a compiler optimizes generated code depends a lot on the compiler. There is such a wide variety in implementations that it is impossible to give a general answer. You need to ask specific questions for specific implementations. One implementation does not much and uses a virtual machine, another one compiles whole programs to C, a third one runs on the JVM, a fourth one does some type inference and generates machine code directly, ...  All very different.

Comment: I understand that the information is used differently by different implementations. My question is more about how to provide the most information without being redundant.

Comment: That's very different for each implementation.

Comment: It's not like people haven't written portable common lisp libraries. When writing such a library, what general rules should be followed?

Comment: write type declarations everywhere, since the dumbest implementation will infer and propagate nothing. Usually high-performance code cares only about a few implementations - even those can be cery different.

Comment: Here's my simple approach: step 1) Make it work. 2) declare optimization settings. 3) Observe the list of compiler warnings related to efficiency. 4) Fix every such warning, whenever possible. Type declarations in Lisp are extremely verbose, so you actually gain some readability, if you are able to elude some of them.

Comment: @nbtrap: When I was getting into optimizing common lisp I found this series of posts interesting (be sure to start from the bottom) http://nklein.com/tags/optimization/

Comment: @wvxvw Thanks. Does that mean that many of the compilers will complain when they're told to optimize for speed but don't have maximal information?

Comment: They would certainly try, but some times programmers may be smarter and find more ways to optimize.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title, you should use declarations when you want the human reader to know that certain values have certain types. 
Premature optimization is a waste of programmer's time and machine cycles.

Now, your specific list:

a. What kind of optimization do you have in mind? The compiler will know the return value type, but how it will use this knowledge is very much implementation dependent.

b,c. Most likely yes. Otherwise it will have to load the file before compilation or recompile `bar` after it sees `foo`.

d. Probably yes.

e. If the compiler knows about the functions `foo` &c when it is compiling the `let` form, it should be able to use that knowledge. If the files where the functions are defined have not been loaded yet, then the declaration is necessary. Note however that you might get in a very serious trouble (e.g., segfault) if you lie to the compiler.

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn't really attempt to answer my question. I've clarified question (a), so please see that again. Question (d) was of the form "should I do this or this", so I can't decipher your answer. Thanks.

Comment: My first paragraph is trying to tell you that your thinking about declarations is wrong.

Comment: I think it's wrong on both points. First of all, the reference to premature optimization is just irrelevant. But the point about using declarations for the benefit of the human reader--suggesting that that's the primary purpose of declarations--is just incorrect.

Comment: SICP: "... a computer language is not just a way of getting a computer to perform operations, but rather ... it is a novel formal medium for expressing ideas about methodology"